# How to cache specific parts of the page with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm making a "reputation" type feature on my site similar to stack overflow. 
I want to display their points on by their name in the header.

I don't want to have to do a db call just for this every time they move to another page.

Can anyone suggest a nice way to implement this?

Comment: Are you using an ORM like Linq-to-Sql or Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3):

Don't make a db call just for this but get the data from the database while you're getting everything else.

Follow the principle of One Request Response cycle, one database call. It's really just a matter of joining in the other tables in your query.

For instance, if you look at a page that has a question and a bunch of answers. You know the "user" of the original question and you know the "user" of each of the answers and comments. So while you're getting the information also join in the pertinent information of each of the users. It's really just joining in additional tables and you can effectively get all of the data you require in one database call.

When you make a call to a database (like MSSQL server) you can get back multiple resultsets in one call, so you're also not limited to a single result set.

Edit:

Here is a sample Stored procedure (or just SQL statements) that results in 5 result sets in one database call.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPostWithSlug]
@PostSlug varchar(80)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @PostId int;

    SELECT @PostId = PostId
    FROM dbo.Post
    WHERE PostSlug = @PostSlug

    SELECT      PostId, PostDate, PostSlug, dbo.[User].UserFirstName + ' ' + dbo.[User].UserLastName AS PostedBy, PostTitle, PostText, PostIsPublished, PostIsPublic, PostTitleImg, PostUpdatedDate, dbo.[User].UserWebsite AS AuthorWebsite
    FROM        dbo.Post
                INNER JOIN
                    dbo.[User]
                        ON dbo.[User].UserId = dbo.Post.UserId

    WHERE       PostId = @PostId

    /* SubCategories for Post */
    SELECT   dbo.PostSubCategory.PostId, dbo.Category.CategoryId, dbo.SubCategory.SubCategoryId, dbo.Category.CategoryDescription, dbo.SubCategory.SubCategoryDescription
    FROM     dbo.Category
             INNER JOIN
                dbo.SubCategory ON dbo.Category.CategoryId = dbo.SubCategory.CategoryId
             INNER JOIN
                dbo.PostSubCategory ON dbo.SubCategory.SubCategoryId = dbo.PostSubCategory.SubCategoryId
             INNER JOIN
                dbo.Post ON dbo.Post.PostId = dbo.PostSubCategory.PostId
    WHERE   dbo.Post.PostId = @PostId
    ORDER BY dbo.PostSubCategory.PostId

    /* Tags for Post */
    SELECT  dbo.PostTag.PostId, dbo.Tag.TagId, dbo.Tag.TagDescription
    FROM    dbo.PostTag
            INNER JOIN
                dbo.Tag ON dbo.Tag.TagId = dbo.PostTag.TagId
            INNER JOIN 
                dbo.Post ON dbo.Post.PostId = dbo.PostTag.PostId
    WHERE   dbo.Post.PostId = @PostId           
    ORDER BY dbo.PostTag.PostId, dbo.Tag.TagDescription

    /* Custom Groups for Post */
    SELECT dbo.PostCustomGroup.PostId, dbo.CustomGroupHeader.CustomGroupHeaderId, dbo.CustomGroup.CustomGroupId
    FROM dbo.CustomGroup
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.CustomGroupHeader ON dbo.CustomGroupHeader.CustomGroupHeaderId = dbo.CustomGroup.CustomGroupHeaderId
        INNER JOIN
            dbo.PostCustomGroup ON dbo.PostCustomGroup.CustomGroupId = dbo.CustomGroup.CustomGroupId
    WHERE   dbo.PostCustomGroup.PostId = @PostId


    EXEC GetCommentsForPost @PostId
END
```

In C# code, your DbDataReader will hold multiple result sets and these can be got by calling NextResult(). Or if you're filling a DataSet you can simply use the Fill method of a adapter.

I use this technique on my blog [Matlus - Internet Technology and Software Engineering](http://www.matlus.com) and you can see how fast (responsive) the site is. The same technique is used on [ExposureRoom](http://exposureroom.com) which is a public social networking website that has a huge amount of traffic.

Comment: +1 @Shiv You make 2 great points here, you should either add some example code, or link to articles that demonstrate what you're talking about.  It'll be more likely to grab you upvotes.  One article that shows the multiple recordsets technique is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163854.aspx#S8

Comment: @Ben, Didn't know multiple record sets was a "new" technique :). I do it all the time. I'll edit my answer to include a sample

Comment: @Shiv You'd be surprised just how often I've found this technique could've been used in places it hasn't been.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned Im using linq to sql

Comment: This technique won't solve the problem of large table scans to calculate points over a ledger like system.  The milliseconds of sql call overhead that you save will never compare to the overall cost of performing point calculation queries.

Comment: jfar, nor will doughnut caching. You're making assumptions about a lot of things in your proposal as well as in what I recommended. Table scans can be avoided by proper design and memory on the database box. After all caching requires memory as well so it's not like anything comes for free. To cache user details on a site like SO where potentially user details change by the second and each page potentially has a different set of users, there will be a lot of stuff in cache that hardly every gets used or is constantly stale and will need to have a really good invalidation strategy.

Comment: Multiple points in the system potentially alter user data, that's a lot of cache invalidation going on making your proposed scheme not deliver. In situations where the data being cached does not change often doughnut caching or any other form of caching works well. But in this scenario I sincerely doubt it.

Comment: @raklos, the concept remains the same. That is, join in the other information in the same call.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for some way to do donut hole caching:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[asp.net-mvc]+donut+hole+caching

Comment: It looks like that method is no longer recommended: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a small part of part of page that needs to be cached, you could use child action to render that part, and cache it. Example: http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#_Toc276711791